# Calculate 'nearest neighbour' when using group_by() in R

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse, dplyr, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to find the centroids location of GPS coordinates within trackline segments. Then find the indexes of nearest neighbours between these centroid points and GPS coordinates in the same trackline segment.

So far I have found the centroid of each segment, and then found a method to get the indexes of these nearest neighbours to my GPS coordinates, but am unable to make R only find nearest neighbours within the same segment.

```
# Calculate the average Latitude/Longitude for each 'Segment'
data_update <- data %>% as.tibble() %>% 
group_by(Segment) %>% mutate(ave_lat = mean(Latitude), ave_lon = mean(Longitude))


# Find the nearest neighbour
install.packages('RANN')
library(RANN)

closest <- RANN::nn2(data_update[,2:3], data_update[,4:5], k = 1, searchtype = "radius", radius = 1) 
closest <- sapply(closest, cbind) %>% as_tibble

# closest produces two columns nn.idx and nn.dist - I need nn.idx only

# data_update[,2] = Longitude values (decimal degrees)
# data_update[,3] = Latitude values (decimal degrees)
# data_update[,4] = average longitude value for each Segment (decimal degrees)
# data_update[,5] = average latitude value for each Segment (decimal degrees)
```

I need to use nn2 to calculate the nn.idx within each 'Segment' rather than across the entire data frame as the code above is doing.

Does anyone know how to group the nn2 function to calculate the nearest neighbour by 'Segment'? I am open to non-tidyverse options also.

Example data can be found here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/16cZPo6kXIafU0ezAoy8EgB9CHVEDUTe-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't follow exactly what you need to do, could you provide some more detailed explanation, please? I don't understand how you can calculate nn2 _within_ segments because `nn2` requires two pieces of information i.e. two sets of coorindates.

Comment: The two sets of coordinates are in the same data frame - first set is Longitude and Latitude columns and second set is ave_lon and ave_lat columns. Need to find nn.idx of ave_lon/ave_lat values that are closest to Longitude/Latitude within each segment. Does this make more sense?